# Google Query Language: filter by date

Tags: sql, google-visualization, google-query-language

I'm trying to add a filter by date in a Google Visualization API query, but I'm doing something wrong with the syntax...

This is the code without the date filter:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G where upper(A) like upper("keyword") or upper(F) like upper("keyword") order by B DESC');
```

I want to add an AND and also add the condition that date in ColB must be >= of 1st Aug 2016.

So I tried with:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G where upper(A) like upper("keyword") or upper(F) like upper("keyword") AND upper(B) >= date "2016-08-01" order by B DESC');
```

But the syntax is probably wrong as the query gets interrupted.

Comment: If issue is with query then remove the php code and just post the query: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/asking-good-questions-421f08ee7e5c#.isyi65fch

Comment: @danihp done now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `B` is a date your error is:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: upper takes a text parameter

To solve it just remove `upper` function.

IF `B` is just a string then automatic type casting is done and query should run without problems.

[image]

Comment: I tried with `upper(B)` and I got `Uncaught Error: Missing query for request id: undefined`. With `B` the table appears but the date parameter is not taken into account (Also elements < `date` are showing).. the locale of the sheet is Italian, but I don't think that has any impact.